# Dynamic list of radio buttons - how do I retrieve value instead of retrieve BY VALUE

Tags: php, jquery, post, get

I have a list of radio buttons that gets loaded from a database. $missing below is a mysql query result in which I retrieve labels for my radio buttons. That part works a-okay:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="col1">
    <div>
        <div id="dam_return">
        <form method="post" action="#" >';
        foreach ($missing as &$path) {
            $prov = $path['template_name'];
            $return .= '<input type="radio" name="radio_group1" value="$prov" class="radios">'.$prov."</option>";
            $return .= '<br>';
        }   
    $return .= '</form>';
```

I inject this return value from the above into my HTML elsewhere in my PHP code (and yes I properly close the divs after, etc.). This part works fine so far.

So then, I have a listener for my class of radio buttons:

```
$(".radios").click(function () {
        $('[id$=mytextbox]').val("asdadasd");
        $.get('?page=EntitlementTemplates&action=dothething&var1=somestuff', function() {
                $(node).removeClass('selected');
                $(node).addClass('delete');
            });

    //location.reload();
});
```

Now here is me reading my get:

```
 if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            switch (strtolower($_GET['action'])) {

                case 'dothething' :
                //I want to manipulate/identify the selected radio button
                break;
```

In this get code, I want to get the value of the radio button that is pressed. There are many examples online using a switch statement for a discrete list of values... but I want to retrieve the radio button BY value. I will use this radio button value to then load some new data to the page... but right now I don't know how to get what radio button was selected? I can't seem to find anything for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass the clicked element value to your server in your click event hanler, you have to pass it as a parameter in your GET-request query.

In your click handler:

```
$(".radios").click(
        $('[id$=mytextbox]').val("asdadasd");
        var radioValue = $(this).val(); 
        $.get('?page=EntitlementTemplates&action=dothething&var1=somestuff&clickedRadioValue='+radioValue , function() {
                $(node).removeClass('selected');
                $(node).addClass('delete');
            });

    //location.reload();
});
```

In your php script:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
            switch (strtolower($_GET['action'])) {
                case 'dothething' :
                $clickedRadioValue = $_GET['clickedRadioValue'];
                //further manipulations
                break;

               //other cases
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected value will be delivered under the name of the radio group; in this case: `$_POST['radio_group1']` ... it is under `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` because of the method specified on your form.

Comment: Oh? Can I change `<form method="post" action="#" >` to `<form method="get" action="#" >` and then $_GET['radio_group1'] will contain a value I can manipulate (and can be manipulated in the 'dothething' block?)

Comment: Yes... but then values will be passed in the querystring and be a readable part of the URL. If you're okay with that, it's fine. Why don't you want to use `$_POST`? I think it looks much cleaner.